# Resizing the image saved on S3, using django + django storages + boto

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

Trying to resize the images on S3 using django + django storages + boto. Below is the snippet,

```
sbs = S3BotoStorage()

# create a copy of the original image
file_o = sbs.open(name, 'r')
image_t = Image.open(file_o).copy()
file_o.close()

# resize the image
image_t.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# overwrite or create new(changing name to name_new) the image
file_n = sbs.open(name, 'w')
image_t.save(file_n, 'JPEG')
image_t.close()
file_n.close()
```

This was working good with `django 1.7.4 + django-storages 1.1.8 + boto 2.36.0`. 
But stopped working after the upgrades `django 1.9.2 + django-storages 1.4 + boto 2.39.0`.

No error is thrown. Code executes just fine, but the image(`name`) will still be of the original size (`1000*1000` instead of `500*500`). Even if we change the file name in `file_n` to a different one(`name_new`), the new file is not created.

The same snippet works good with `FileSystemStorage`.

Comment: Problem seems to be in `django-storages 1.4`. Did not decode much, but `django 1.9.2 + boto 2.39.0 + django-storages 1.1.8` is working alright.